Bollywood film of the 60s, includes Himalayan Hiking Club
I saw a 60s (maybe 70s) potboiler a few weeks ago and can't remember the name of it.
It was a story about a man who could not have children from an accidental fall down the steps (!) who becomes the head of the Himalayan Hiking Club.  A hiker from East Africa comes to the club and meets the neighbor who grows apples. They fall in love and as a result of one night of bliss she becomes pregnant.
In the meantime, the East African hiker gets caught in an avalanche and is in hospital for 4 months. Thinking he is dead and desperate, the woman marries the Club Director. The mother lies to the hiker when he returns and he goes home to East Africa dejected.
The hiker comes back six years later and unwittingly meets and becomes "Uncle" to his six year old son Bobby. Lots of drama when the parents see him return and the hiker realizes he is the biological father. In the end the non bio father gives his wife and son to the biological father as he dies.
There is so much more to this film, but perhaps this is enough to get help on it. I read up on it and the male lead became a famous director in his later years.  The female lead went by only one name.

Welcome to the community. If you know, what are the names of these lead actors? You said there is much more to the film. If you know more details, I suggest putting it into your narrative.  I hope you enjoy this place as much as I have.

not sure about bollywood version but here rhe telugu version https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intlo_Illalu_Vantintlo_Priyuralu

The movie is the Hindi classic "Ek Phool Do Mali" starring Sanjay Khan, Balraj Sahni, Sadhana released in 1969.
Wikipedia Link: Ek Phool Do Mali
After reading the story as described in the question, I remembered the movie and cross checked through Wikipedia to confirm the same.

You might want to elaborate in which way this fits to the details from the question in order to flesh out this answer a little more.
